# Designing good classes and hierarchies

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I am learning C# and have decided to write a class library for matrices and their functionality to gain some experience and practice.

Okay, now I have the following class model:

```
class Matrix // For rectangular matrices
{ }

class SquareMatrix : Matrix
{ }
class RowMatrix : Matrix
{ }
class ColumnMatrix : Matrix
{ }
```

Each of the classes have a suitable constructor to take the dimensions or order of the particular matrix.

Now my SquareMatrix class has a specific function to find and return the determinant. The issue I am facing here is if a user of my library makes an instance of type Matrix with dimensions n and n, then he will be unable to use the Determinant() method as it resides only in SquareMatrix whereas his instance is of type Matrix.

Similar problems can occur with other methods as well.

---

So my questions are:

1. Is my class design flawed?
2. Is there any way to tackle this issue? (Or (though it has a rare chance) should I rather expect the user to instantiate the objects correctly?)

Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: There's no perfect solution, the relationship is just not represented well in terms of inheritance. See [circle-ellipse problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem).

Comment: Really good link, thank you!

Comment: Well so of course the simplest solution would be to simply get away with all the inheritance and have exceptions or bool returns to check validity. But that's not really much of OOP is that...

Answer (score 1):

What you're battling against here is the Liskov Substitution principle. Basically what you need to do is not use the old "... is a ..." for working out super/sub classes. Instead try to use "...Is substitutable for..."

If you're just starting out in C# your first stop should be learning the principles of SOLID. For your answer work on S and L

This will help you with L, http://www.oodesign.com/liskov-s-substitution-principle.html

Check this one out for SOLID, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/703634/SOLID-architecture-principles-using-simple-Csharp

When you want to work on I and D hit me up, they're my favourite

Dale

Answer (score 1):

Nice Question.

I would think:

The user should be responsible for instantiating the correct instance. If the user wants a Matrix, then that's what he gets. If that function does not exist in Matrix, then that's too bad.

However, if you had a common function which behaved differently depending on what type of Matrix it was, then in that case you would create a factory that returns a Matrix. It would return the appropriate Matrix based on the parameters. The user would call the function on Matrix, but it's behavior would actually be different depending on what Matrix you actually returned.

Comment: Good idea. So I could make all constructors private and have another static member to instantiate and return a matrix of the appropriate type. But then would I not require the user to use 'dynamic' creation of objects to allow this? And does dynamic not have a mild performance hit?